# I am running Paranoid Android 3.97 but Root Checker is showing me that my Nexus 4 is not rooted

Tags: root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean

I am running Paranoid Android and Franco Kernel but I do not have access to data/data folder is empty. [Root Checker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) is showing me that my phone is not rooted for some reason. It was working fine when i was on Android 4.2.2(Paranoid Android 3.67). How can i fix this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to Flash the Kernel first and THEN root the device. In 4.3 google have implmended a securty feature which causes some rooting problems.